# How to sort a multi-dimensional array by the second array in descending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array in JavaScript.

```
var array = [[12,3],[10,2],[8,1],[12,3],[7,1],[6,1],[4,1],[10,2],[12,3]]
```

I would like to sort this array by the second value in descending order. The expected output is

```
[[12,3],[12,3],[12,3],[10,2][10,2],[8,1],[7,1],[6,1],[4,1]
```

I've tried

```
array.sort(function(array) {
  return array[1] - array[1]
}
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Sorting single-dimensional arrays is easy but I'm not sure how to do it with multi-dimensional arrays.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for the sort function is a bit off. Your function should take two parameters. The following sorts descending by the second position in the inner arrays.

```js
var array = [[12,3],[10,2],[8,1],[12,3],[7,1],[6,1],[4,1],[10,2],[12,3]];
console.log(array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
}));
```

Comment: Nice, you could also do `return b[1] - a[1]`

Comment: @RichardHamilton yes, [it's actually better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison) to return a number instead of a boolean in the sort comparison. I updated the answer to reflect that